# How to Generate A Slug on AppSync Mutation

Tags: aws-appsync

I have a mutation to create a new `Event`. However I want to be able to reference/get that `Event` using a friendly id or slug instead of the DynamoDB primary key of `id`. Ideally this would use the `city` field from the input to generate the slug. However each slug must be unique per author

How can I generate a friendly slug in my mutation that is based on the city name and unique (per author) ?

#### Schema

```
type Event {
    id: ID!
    subtitle: String!
    city: String!
    author: String!
    created: AWSDateTime
}
```

#### mutation.CreateEvent

```
#set( $attribs = $util.dynamodb.toMapValues($ctx.args.input))
#set( $attribs.author = $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDB($ctx.identity.username))
#set( $attribs.created = $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDB($util.time.nowFormatted("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ")))
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "PutItem",
  "key": {
    "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId()),
  },
  "attributeValues": $util.toJson($attribs),
  "condition": {
    "expression": "attribute_not_exists(#id)",
    "expressionNames": {
      "#id": "id",
    },
  },
}
```

```

Comment: You would probably have to store the slug in a different table, where the author is the hash key and the slug probably the sort key. Also, you will have to write logic that checks if a slug candidate is available in the table before creating it, and trying something different if it fails. In that case I would recommend using the Lambda data source.

Comment: @Tinou could i use the new Pipeline Resolvers instead in this case somehow?